# Join on today's date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which allows me to look up a date and then retrieve what financial period, week it belongs to etc.

The format of this table is as follows:

> Date (DATETIME)
>
> FinancialPd
>
> FinancialWk
>
> FinancialYr

What I would like to be able to do is to take todays date, and find out what financial period it belongs to for report automation.

So far I have tried:

```
SELECT 
SUM(Revenue) as revenue,
periods.Date,
periods.financialPd

FROM

[tbl].[dbo].[view] ordTbl

INNER JOIN [tbl].[dbo].[caltbl] as periods
ON GETDATE() = periods.Date
```

My expected result would be something like:

Today: 2017-01-15 00:00:00

Financial Period: 1

Revenue: 1582.08

EDIT**

TDLR; I need to take TODAYS date, look it up in my calendar table, and return the appropriate financial period.

Comment: You are confusing JOIN with WHERE. Join your view with the calendar table using whatever date column is appropriate. If you only want today's orders, add a WHERE clause that filters either the view or calendar table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no this is not about orders, this is about working out what financial period today's date belongs to.

Comment: Then why did you put that view in there? Why did you use JOIN? Just use `WHERE` on the calendar table.

Comment: You could put the date comparison in joining clause but need an extra condition to relate each table, otherwise it will work kind similar to `Cross Join`, so it should be a query like `...ON ordTbl.** = periods.** AND CAST(periods.Date) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date)`. But it is suggested to put predicate in `WHERE` clause for easier reading.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because I will be using information from the view. I am joining the period onto my date to calculate the time frame for the data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used a join as I need to join today's date with the periods table. I have no other way to get the information otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) comment, you should be using a `WHERE` clause.

Seems like you want to cast the dates (`datetime` values) to a `date` value, try this:

```
SELECT periods.Date, periods.financialPd
FROM [tbl].[dbo].[view] ordTbl
INNER JOIN [tbl].[dbo].[caltbl] as periods
ON periods.[YourJoinField] = ordTbl.[YourJoinField]
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE = CAST(periods.Date AS DATE)
```

You may not need the second cast, depending on the data type of `periods.Date`.

Not sure if this is a simplified version of the query, but you don't select anything from `ordTbl` so that join may not be required at all.

If you don't require the orders table, then you just want something like this:

```
SELECT periods.Date, periods.financialPd
FROM [tbl].[dbo].[caltbl] as periods
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE = CAST(periods.Date AS DATE)
```

The reason for the `CAST` is that `GETDATE()` will return a `datetime` value, so:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Returns: `2017-09-07 15:49:54.233` which will never be equal to: `2017-09-07` as it will default to: `2017-09-07 00:00:00.000`

Comment: No need to cast the calendar table's date. It *should* be a `date` or `datetime` without a time portion

Comment: My [YourJoinField] is the current date GetDate().

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i wasn't sure, hence the line: _You may not need the second cast, depending on the data type of periods.Date._

Comment: @Tanner I need to join onto my periods table with today's date.

Comment: @80gm2 show the schema of your order table please and i will edit the answer accordingly, at the moment, you are not showing why you are joining to that table

Comment: @80gm2 If you have some dummy data and the desired output that would help too.

Comment: I have added some info in, I am just trying to for now, say, get todays date and tell me which financial period it belongs to. Almost like a VLOOKUP in Excel, and then I will sum revenue, orders etc. @Tanner